# How do I know if an app is already in the process of opening?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Sometimes some apps take like minutes to open because my laptop is too slow, but sometimes I'm not sure if it's just taking its time or if I misclicked. I don't wanna click open the app again in case the both of them suddenly opens at once and further lag out my PC, but I don't wanna just sit there either.

So, how do I know if an app is already in the process of opening?

Comment: An app will always show up in the task mananger under processes. Additionally, you can choose to assign playing a sound for opening programs in windows. Like a click sound. This way, when you start a program, if you hear that sound playing, you can guarantee that you clicked it, and it will open.

Answer (score 2):

Different apps do different things while opening and it is not always possible to know.

If it is not showing up in the task bar (it may not), then open Task Manager and you will see it in the Processes Tab.

Also determine the normal opening time of apps on your own machine (by observation) and wait that normal time.